# How to automate generating environment-specific builds in ASP.NET without TFS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, automation, continuous-integration, build-automation

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. The solution is ASP.NET MVC 5. Using Bitbucket for source control. We don't use TFS.

Right now, if QA wants a build for a release, I have to go into Visual Studio, right-click the project, click Publish, select the QA build profile, select the correct target location based on the environment we want to deploy to and the new build version, check what the latest git commit hash is, append that hash to the end of the build folder so they know what version of the build it is, etc. We are using latest git commit hash as a way to track the build version of a particular release. Then I click Publish and it puts the build in a drop folder.

Then QA finds a bug, and I have to go through this manual process all over again. And the information I have to enter changes, because any code change means the git commit hash will change. Eventually I would like it to be set up so that all I have to do is commit a fix to the release branch and QA can click a button to generate a build off of this commit and deploy it themselves. But automating the first part would be a good first step. I also have to do these same steps manually for builds for other environments, such as preprod and prod.

What would be the best tools/ways to automate something like this? Once again, we don't use TFS.

Comment: Without TFS I don't think you can use the "Commit" to trigger anything. At least I couldn't find a way, alternatives involve polling bitbucket for changes.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Of course you can. TFS isn't the only tool around.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. There are many different tools out there to set up continuous deployment. Explaining how to use them would be too broad of a topic.

Comment: This is **NOT** too broad, prove it, give Steve *one* method to do it then @mason

Comment: @JeremyThompson I can think of at least 5 off the top of my head. You really don't think "How do I automate builds and releases?" is too broad? Seems like the very definition of too broad. I won't be providing any here because this is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You're thinking about this as very general "automate buiilds and releases" but the point is very simple, make the Commit button trigger anything (without TFS) use any tool you want.

Comment: @Steve Dolan are you looking for a way to automatically trigger builds or looking for a "script" so you don't have to teach QA to use VS to make builds?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I think the main goal would be automating the steps in my second paragraph.

Comment: Where and how do you need to set the commit hash? you could call `git` from within msbuild to get some repo information to use during builds..

Comment: Devops wants the folder that contains the build they are going to deploy to be in this format: [major version].[minor version].[commit hash]. Looking into MSBuild now, will that do everything I described?